# Snapping issues in Adobe Illustrator cs6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I'm having snapping issues in Adobe Illustrator. After checking the different snap options, nothing seems to help. There are moments when designing where the program won't let me snap to an exact point, and only just before or just after.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me what would be causing this? And what might be able to be done about it? I've been working in Illustrator for years, and I've never had a problem like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Check that Align to Pixel Grid is off in the Transform panel

Comment: You should also check your boxes: they've 3-digit decimals in a pixel format, which really shouldn't be the case.